# String reverse error

Tags: c++, string

Can anyone explain to me why im getting a ".exe has encountered a problem and needs close"error, it compiles and works sometimes when i fiddle with the char array, but when it does work i sometimes get strange characters at the end of the string.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char* StrReverse3(char*);
char* StrReverse3(char* str)
{
    char *p;

    int length=0,start=0,end=0;
    length=strlen(str);

    for(start=0,end=length-1;end>= 0,start<=length-1;end--,start++)
    {
        p[start]=str[end];
    }   


    return p;
}
int main()
{
  char str[100]="Saw my reflection in snow covered hills";
  StrReverse3(str);

cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's also reversing the string wrong by the way....

Comment: thats not what my output is telling me

Comment: You're right your ouput is "Segmentation Fault"

Comment: There's also no need to initialise `length`, `start` or `end` to `0`, you define them all again in the for loop initialisation. Two for loop conditions are also unnecessary, one of them will suffice.

Comment: In the comma expression `end>= 0,start<=length-1;` only the last operand returns a value; the first operand is evaluated and the result discarded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not initializing p. It's an uninitialized  pointer that you are writing to.

Since you are writing this in C++, not C, I'd suggest using `std::string` and [`std::reverse`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/):

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Saw my reflection in snow covered hills";
    std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
    std::cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sllih derevoc wons ni noitcelfer ym waS
```

See it working online at [ideone](http://ideone.com/iMb1B)

Answer (score 3):

`char *p;` is never initialized, yet `p[start]` is used as the destination of an assignment. Don't you get compiler warnings from this? I'm amazed it even "works sometimes".

Comment: That might be the random garbage he's seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing memory that wasn't allocated by your program (p can point anywhere!). This is the reason for the problems you have.

I strongly encourage you to

- read into the topic of dynamically allocating memory with new and delete to understand a very important topic
- read into the standard template library, especially std::string. You should not use raw pointers like char*, always use standard types when possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

char* StrReverse3(char* str){
    int length=0,start=0,end=0;
    length=strlen(str);

    for(start=0,end=length-1;end > start;end--,start++){
        char temp;
        temp = str[start];
        str[start]=str[end];
        str[end]=temp;
    }

    return str;
}
int main(){
  char str[100]="Saw my reflection in snow covered hills";
  cout << StrReverse3(str);
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```